# Error message: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: SqlGroup: Failed to acquire lock on cache key

Tags: wordpress

I have CiviCRM running in WordPress on a development website and I got the following error message from WordPress. WordPress says that the page where the error was caught was the wp-login.php page. The text of the error message is:

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 114 of the file ... /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Cache/SqlGroup.php. Error message: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: SqlGroup: Failed to acquire lock on cache key.

The Civi Log lists the following that seems potentially related:

$backTrace = #0 ... /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(433): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 ... /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 ... /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1169): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

I am trying to figure out how to start diagnosing the problem. Thank you for any suggestions.

Edited to add, I never found a solution to this. For unrelated reasons it became moot so I stopped digging.

Comment: did you figure anything out. just had a site hitting this. suspecting an issue with Parent Groups that are also Smart Groups but that is a bit of staring at tea leaves thus far

Comment: Bump - Did you or @petednz-fuzion ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: I checked back and saw that in that scenario it was that A ws Parent Group. B and C were child Groups. B and C were both Smart Groups. BUT A was also a Smart Group for those in B and C. Which was not necessary as by default a Parent Group includes those in its Child Groups